# Most efficient way to set n consecutive bits to 1?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want to get a function that will set the `n` last bits of a numerical type to `1`. For example:

```
bitmask (5) = 0b11111 = 31
bitmask (0) = 0
```

I, first, had this implementation (`mask_t` is just a `typedef` around `uint64_t`):

```
mask_t bitmask (unsigned short n) {
  return ((((mask_t) 1) << n) - 1;
}
```

Everything is fine except when the function hit `bitmask (64)` (the size of `mask_t`), then I get `bitmask (64) = 0` in place of 64 bits set to `1`.

So, I have two questions:

1. Why do I have this behavior ? Pushing the `1` by 64 shifts on the left should clear the register and remain with `0`, then applying the `-1` should fill the register with `1`s...
2. What is the proper way to achieve this function ?

Comment: You *do* remember that bit-numbers are zero-based? So for a 64-bit integer the bits are numbers `0` through `63` (inclusive). That means bit number 64 is invalid. Perhaps you should add some checks for valid bit numbers?

Comment: Shifting left by 64 bits is undefined behaviour. You may need to special case it with `~0`.

Comment: Why don't you just make 64 bits a special case? Check for `n == 64` and return the result you want...

Comment: How about `(uint64_t)(~0) >> (64 - n)`?

Comment: You're just getting lucky.   Leftshift 64 bits has undefined behaviour, which means the behaviour you see/expect is not guaranteed between compilers.

Comment: Assuming there is a `shl` set of processor instructions, the operand of these instructions that has the number to shift may have requrements including that it is less than the register width. So the _processor_ may do, or do not, _anything_ when this condition is not met. So this is UB of the processor.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage : Your solution is nice but do not work on `0` (I just tried...).

Comment: @perror Ah, yes that would be a problem ...

Comment: @squeamishossifrage If I'm not mistaken, wouldn't that arithmetic shift not change the value since the sign bit is 1?

Comment: @Miket25 `uint64_t` is unsigned. There is no sign bit.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage With `(uint64_t)(~0)`, cast is too late. --> `~((uint64_t)0)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is a well known problem. There are easy ways to implement this function over the range 0..63 and over the range 1..64 (one way has been mentioned in the comments), but 0..64 is more difficult.

Of course you can just take either the "left shifting" or "right shifting" mask generation and then special-case the "missing" `n`,

```
uint64_t bitmask (unsigned short n) {
  if (n == 64) return -((uint64_t)1);
  return (((uint64_t) 1) << n) - 1;
}
```

Or

```
uint64_t bitmask (unsigned short n) {
  if (n == 0) return 0;
  uint64_t full = ~(uint64_t)0;
  return full >> (64 - n);
}
```

Either way tends to compile to a branch, though it technically doesn't *have* to.

You can do it without `if` (not tested)

```
uint64_t bitmask (unsigned int n) {
  uint64_t x = (n ^ 64) >> 6;
  return (x << (n & 63)) - 1;
}
```

The idea here is that we're going to either shift 1 left by some amount the same as in your original code, or 0 in the case that `n = 64`. Shifting 0 left by 0 is just going to be 0 again, subtracting 1 sets all 64 bits.

---

Alternatively if you're on a modern x64 platform and BZHI is available, a very fast (BZHI is fast on all CPUs that implement it) but limited-portability option is:

```
uint64_t bitmask (unsigned int n) {
  return _bzhi_u64(~(uint64_t)0, n);
}
```

This is even well-defined for `n > 64`, the actual count of 1's will be `min(n & 0xFF, 64)` because BZHI saturates but it reads only the lowest byte of the index.

Comment: Alternatively, write `~(mask_t)0` for the 'all ones' value.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot left shift by a value larger than or equal to the bit width of the type in question.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

From section 6.5.7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *2* The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The
>   type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. **If the value
>   of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the
>   width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.**

You'll need to add a check for this in your code:

```
mask_t bitmask (unsigned short n) {
    if (n >= 64) {
        return ~(mask_t)0;
    } else {
        return (((mask_t) 1) << n) - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! I was writing my answer when you posted! I ended-up with the same conclusion. Up-voting because you explain the problem!

Comment: @M.M Thanks.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, just for your information, I ended up by writing:

```
mask_t bitmask (unsigned short n) {
  return  (n < (sizeof (mask_t) * CHAR_BIT)) ? (((mask_t) 1) << n) - 1 : -1;
}
```

But, the answer of harold is so complete and well explained that I will select it as the answer.

Comment: Why use `unsigned short n` when coding goal is "_Most efficient_ way to set n consecutive bits to 1?".  `unsigned n` or `uint_fast8_t n` would be better candidates.

Comment: Rather than magic number 8, which should be [avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad), consider `CHAR_BIT`

Comment: Use of `<` here is nice as function is defined for all `n`, as long as `mask_t` lacks padding.

Comment: @chuck: I didn't know `CHAR_BIT`, thanks for the remark!