# Invert (flip) last n bits of a number with only bitwise operations

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators

Given a binary integer, how can I invert (flip) last n bits using only bitwise operations in c/c++?
For example:

```
// flip last 2 bits
0110 -> 0101
0011 -> 0000
1000 -> 1011
```

Comment: @paulsm4: I think you will find it's not that simple.

Comment: @paulsm4 notice I said **last n bits**, not the whole number, which is not as trivial

Comment: OK, now it is clearer.  But what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @harold I updated the title and the question to clarify the intention. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: In that case we have [set n bits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45352352/555045) and XOR by that mask

Comment: @Christophe I tried a bunch of different bitwise expressions but they were very spagetti so I thought if wouldn't be useful to include in the question

Comment: @BenVoigt I've updated the question to include more examples

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks for pointing out that the question was not clear. I am familiar with XOR but the challenge was to flip the last n bits rather than the whole thing. I added more examples and hopefully the question is more clear now. I wanted to add example code but what I tried was too spagetti and wasn't really helpful so I assumed keeping the question shorter would be more useful. One of my attempts for example: `(u << n) + ~(u & ~(~0U << n))`, which is pretty overkill for this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can flip last n bits of your number with

```
#define flipBits(n,b) ((n)^((1u<<(b))-1))
```

for example `flipBits(0x32, 4)` will flip the last 4 bits and result will be `0x3d`

---

this works because if you think how XOR works

```
 0 ^ 0 => 0
 1 ^ 0 => 1
```

bits ***aren't*** flipped

```
0 ^ 1 => 1
1 ^ 1 => 0
```

bits ***are*** flipped

---

```
 (1<<b)-1
```

this part gets you the last n bits
for example, if b is 4 then `1<<4` is `0b10000` and if we remove 1 we get our mask which is `0b1111` then we can use this to xor with our number to get the desired output.

works for C and C++

Comment: Could be an acceptable answer if you would put the define expression between parenthesis, in order to avoid issues with preprocessing an priority.  Would be much better with an inline function or a template function.

Comment: I think OP wants to reverse those bits, not flip them. @MuhsinFatih, can you give a more helpful example? `0110 -> 0101` can be interpreted as reversing or flipping.

Comment: The behavior of `1<<b` is not defined by the C standard if `b` is the number of bits in an `int` or is one less than that. (If it is one less, the behavior is not defined because the value overflows. If it is equal to the width, it is not defined because the shift operator is limited to a shift of less than the full width.)

Comment: @TonyK I meant flip, updated the question to clarify the intent. Although I am curious, I don't understand the grammar here. How is reverse different than flip? Your example is valid for flipping too

Comment: @MuhsinFatih: reversing all the bits of e.g. `11101001` gives `10010111`. It means writing the bit string backwards.

Comment: Better now :-)  But have you tried `flipBits(0x32,6&5)` which should give the same result than your example since 6&5 is 4?  With define, you need also parenthesis around each parameter you use, since define works with dumb substitution. Demo https://ideone.com/qHefN5

Comment: @TonyK oh that makes sense :)

Comment: I don't know how the answer gets + votes. Seemingly everybody rules overflow bug out.

Comment: using macros is a bad idea if you don't know how it works [The need for parentheses in macros in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/995714)

Comment: Better to use `1u<<(b)` than `1<<(b)`

Comment: `flipBits(n,b)` fails when `n` is wider than `int/unsigned`.

Comment: If you use a macro, make it more generic and handle the largest type: `#define flipBits(n, b) ((n) ^ ((1ULL << (b)) - 1))`